# How to align material icon under link text?

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can I align the down arrow from material icons under the link text? I tried using the `:after` pseudo class, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="jump-to-links">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.jump-to-links {
  .material-icons {
    @include centerX();
    bottom: -20px;
    color: $purple;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
  text-align: center;
  a,a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $black;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12%;
  }
  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/kpvwwveL/6/

Comment: centered under "link" with material-icon included: https://jsfiddle.net/t27je5Lq/

Comment: Did any of the answer below work for you?

Comment: @Pangloss - I discovered another way to fix my issue.

Comment: Nice to hear, just to check since the question is still open. You can accept the one that also works, or post your own answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block to your

```
i{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kpvwwveL/3/

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this as the best way to solve the alignment issue:

```
<div class="jump-to-links">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>


.jump-to-links {
  .material-icons {
    @include centerX();
    bottom: -20px;
    color: $purple;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
  text-align: center;
  a,a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $black;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12%;
  }
  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things and not go the natural way? Which I think is to put line breaks between link text and i.

```
  <a href="#">
    Link
    <br>
    <i class="material-icons arrow-down">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
  </a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weejoy22/